# Error "Access Denied" while uploading file to s3 bucket asp.net core for UploadAsync method

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My bucket policy is below. I have shown the information below as HIDDEN.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "****",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<HIDDEN>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<HIDDEN>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "<HIDDEN>"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Is your bucket set up as publicly accessible ?

Comment: No. not publicly accessible. i want to access it only from my application. I can load file only If i not enable ""Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)" in s3."

Comment: Double check your Id and resource ARN. Also are you running this code locally ? On a remote server ? You have to set up IAM credentials in any case

Comment: i am running code locally. How to set  up IAM credentials ?

Comment: I wrote a more complete answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aws credential file is stored in `~/.aws/credentials` (on Linux) or `"%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials"` on Windows. By default the .NET SDK will retrieve your credentials from this file default profile.

To set up a default profile, you have to write your access key and secret acces keys in this file as follows:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

See [Configuration and Credential File Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) for more details

If you don't have those credentials, you can go to your IAM user in the AWS console and download them as a .csv for example

Comment: is there any speed limit for s3?